# sudo no more working after change to /etc/hosts

Tags: debian, sudo, debian-stretch

I had to add a DNS alias into `/etc/hosts`, and I've added it in first position instead of last, replacing the FQDN.

After this (not right after, but at least the next day), sudo was no more usable, saying for any command:

> Sorry user is not allowed to [command] as root on [new_dns_alias]

What could be the reason of this since the sudoers file doesn't include any hostname ?

Comment: It does, see this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/429790/sudo-command-trying-to-search-for-hostname#429890

Comment: Ok, thanks, interesting. Now I have to test to put the internal DNS name after 127.0.1.1 and the external DNS name after IP, will it resolve FQDN to internal DNS name ?